# How to create an R function which applies function to more than one column in a dataset?

Tags: r, function, date, tidyverse, lubridate

Here is an example dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

db_country <- tibble(country = c("Argentina", "Australia", "Austria"),
                     region = c("Americas", "Asia", "Europe"),
                     start_date = as.numeric(18487, 18487, 18487),
                     end_date = as.numeric(18500, 18500, 18500))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  country   region   start_date end_date
  <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Argentina Americas      18487    18500
2 Australia Asia          18487    18500
3 Austria   Europe        18487    18500
```

I am trying to make a function that converts all values in a column into a date format. This is what I have so far:

```r
mydate <- function(dataset, column) {
  dataset %>% mutate({{column}} := as_date({{column}}))
```

I want to be able to input multiple column names for the "column" argument that I made. Rather than using my `mydate()` function twice for `start_date` and `end_date`, I want to be able to write something like this and apply the function to more than one column using one line of code: (a bit like the `select()` function)

```r
mydate(db_country, start_date, end_date)
```

How can I edit my function to do this?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```r
mydate <- function(dataset, ...) 
{
  mutate(dataset, across(as.character(ensyms(...)), as_date))
}
```

Which allows the following pipe-friendly syntax:

```
db_country %>% mydate(start_date, end_date)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   country   region   start_date end_date  
#>   <chr>     <chr>    <date>     <date>    
#> 1 Argentina Americas 2020-08-13 2020-08-26
#> 2 Australia Asia     2020-08-13 2020-08-26
#> 3 Austria   Europe   2020-08-13 2020-08-26
```

Comment: Also I see `as_name()` suggested instead of `as.character()` within the whole `rlang` framework. I can't say I know the advantages of it. I am sure there is at minimum a nuance where it is safer? It does suggest that there are name repair features planned for the future.

Comment: @Adam yes, although I think that _would_ have to be put inside an `sapply` to work